# Filter numpy ndarray (matrix) according to column values

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

This question is about filtering a `NumPy` `ndarray` according to some column values.

I have a fairly large `NumPy` `ndarray` (300000, 50) and I am filtering it according to values in some specific columns. I have `ndtypes` so I can access each column by name.

The first column is named `category_code` and I need to filter the matrix to return only rows where `category_code` is in `("A", "B", "C")`.

The result would need to be another `NumPy` `ndarray` whose columns are still accessible by the `dtype` names.

Here is what I do now:

```
index = numpy.asarray([row['category_code'] in ('A', 'B', 'C') for row in data])
filtered_data = data[index]
```

List comprehension like:

```
list = [row for row in data if row['category_code'] in ('A', 'B', 'C')]
filtered_data = numpy.asarray(list)
```

wouldn't work because the `dtypes` I originally had are no longer accessible.

**Are there any better / more Pythonic way of achieving the same result?**

Something that could look like:

```
filtered_data = data.where({'category_code': ('A', 'B','C'})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you mean `row['category_code']` instead of `data['category_code']` in the `index =` line?

Comment: I don't really think you need to improve on your existing solution where you (i) build a bool array of the rows satisfying your condition and (ii) using this array to index your data. It's clean, readable, efficient... What else do you want?

Comment: Pierre GM- The example is a simplified one. I actually want to be able to generalize it to multiple columns values (like category_code is amongst those values, and col_2 is in that range, and col_3 is no larger than X, and ...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the ***NumPy***-based library, [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org), which has a more generally useful implementation of *ndarrays*:

```
>>> # import the library
>>> import pandas as PD
```

Create some sample *data* as *python dictionary*, whose *keys* are the column names and whose *values* are the column values as a python list; one key/value pair per column

```
>>> data = {'category_code': ['D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A'], 
            'value':[4, 2, 6, 3, 8, 4, 3, 9]}

>>> # convert to a Pandas 'DataFrame'
>>> D = PD.DataFrame(data)
```

To return just the rows in which the category_code is either B or C, two steps conceptually, but can easily be done in a single line:

```
>>> # step 1: create the index 
>>> idx = (D.category_code== 'B') | (D.category_code == 'C')

>>> # then filter the data against that index:
>>> D.ix[idx]

        category_code  value
   2             B      6
   3             C      3
   6             C      3
```

Note the difference between indexing in *Pandas* versus *NumPy*, the library upon which Pandas is built. In NumPy, you would just place the index inside the brackets, indicating which dimension you are indexing with a ",", and using ":" to indicate that you want all of the values (columns) in the other dimension:

```
>>>  D[idx,:]
```

In Pandas, you call the the data frame's ***ix*** method, and place *only* the index inside the brackets:

```
>>> D.loc[idx]
```

Comment: `D.ix[idx]` is now deprecated ([as of 0.20.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated)) so you would use `D.loc[idx]` in your last line instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you can choose, I strongly recommend [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org): it has ["column indexing" built-in](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#additional-column-access) plus a lot of other features. It is built on numpy.

Comment: Looks pretty awesome. Gonna give it a try. I'm using this as an input for the scikit-learn library. It looks like pandas also help with reading data from csv and handle missing data. I guess I reimplemented a bunch of it for nothing :)